# how to compile sass to css without getting npm error

Tags: css, node.js, npm, sass

When compiling **SASS** to **CSS** I always get this error

```
An output directory must be specified when compiling a directory
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! natours@1.0.0 compile:sass: `node-sass scss/main.scss css/style.css`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the natours@1.0.0 compile:sass script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/haq/.npm/_logs/2020-08-27T13_30_14_538Z-debug.log
```

Comment: As error says - you haven't provided an output directory or you have provided an invalid one. Double check it!

Answer (score 2):

Correct syntax is `node-sass scss/main.scss -o css/styles.css`

Edit:

node-sass require you to explicitly specify the output folder/file the `-o` option is here for that !

To explain all the command :

- you first call `node-sass`
- then you specify the scss file (see him as the input)
- `-o` the option to specify the output folder
- then the output folder/file

If you need more information about the node-sass options go to his npm page, it's well documented : https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass

Comment: Can you explain to OP why that is the correct way to write the command?

Answer (score 0):

To compile sass with npm you need to

**1. Install node-sass. In this case, it will install locally in the current directory.**

`npm install node-sass`

This will install node-sass in the `node_modules` folder

**2. Call node-sass and give the input and output file.**

This is the folder structure for this example

```
|project/
├─ css/
│  ├─ style.scss
├─ node_modules/
│  ├─ .bin/
│  │  ├─ node-sass
├─ index.html
├─ package-lock.json
├─ package.json
```

So, call the compiler and pass the input and output files.

`node_modules/.bin/node-sass css/style.scss css/style.css`

`node_modules/.bin/node-sass` is the call for the sass compiler

`css/style.scss` is the input file

`css/style.css` is the output file